# No me manda a la URL / página que le indico

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-router-dom

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en ReactJS, en el cual en el archivo `App.js` quiero usar el menú de navegación de Bootstrap para llamar todas la páginas.

Esto es el archivo `App.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ReactDOM } from 'react-dom/client';
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Listenf from "./componentes/catalogos/enfermedades/Listar-enfermedades";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
     <Router>
         <div className="container">
              <nav className="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-light">
                  <div className="nav navbar-nav">
                      <a className="nav-item nav-link active" href="/">Sistema <span className="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                      <a className="nav-item nav-link" href="/">Inicio</a>
                      <a className="nav-item nav-link" href="/listarenf" >Enfermedades</a>
                  </div>
              </nav>
                  
                  <Route exact path='/' component={Index} ></Route>
                  <Route exact path='/listarenf' component={Listenf} ></Route>
          </div>              
      </Router>        
  );
}
export default App;
```

Esto es lo que marca en la consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Soy nuevo en ReactJS, por lo tanto no entiendo, ¿Alguna solución?.

Comment: Al parecer estas estructurando mal las rutas, ya que el error te indica que el componente `<Route />` debe estar envuelto en `<Routes />`. [Acá](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69832748/error-error-a-route-is-only-ever-to-be-used-as-the-child-of-routes-element) te dejo una respuesta que podría servirte de guía.

Comment: Verificando. Gracias.

Comment: Gracias, Paulo Urbano Rivera. Por tu ayuda, eso resolvió mi problema.

Y una ultima nota: Para todos aquellos que estamos aprendiendo ReactJs, hay muchos cambios y los tutoriales que hay en YouTube son buenos, pero, hay cosas que podrían dar problemas en nuestro aprendizaje y progreso. Saludos.

Comment: por eso también es importante ir consultando la documentación oficial y considerar la versión en la que se está trabajando de igual manera. Me alegro que te haya resultado, saludos y feliz código!